# Threading on MingW

Tags: multithreading, compilation, mingw, codeblocks

I have recently been trying to compile some data and used MingW with Code::Blocks. The compilation wouldn't finish with success because of the threading being unavaiable. Is there any way i could enable threading and compile this way?

Comment: You should provide the relevant code that your asking about.

Comment: Make sure that `std=gnu++11` is specified as an option to the compiler (if you're using C++11 `std::thread`). Support for threads in MinGW distributions is mixed.  Recent versions of TDM's MinGW support both pthreads and C++11 threads: http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/  TDM MinGW is very easy to install. I'm not sure how to integrate it into Code::Blocks, but I'd guess it wouldn't be too difficult.